# Gapless between image

Tags: html, css

There would be a gap between left and right photos. How do I produce a gapless? I tried using float and display which seem not workable?

```
echo '<li><a href="'.$row['id'].'"><img alt="'.$row['username'].'" src="photo/'.$phm.'"></img></a></li>';
```

Comment: Do you use JQuery to change the list display to horizontal? Can you post the CSS?

Comment: How can there be a gap when there is only one `<img />` in that markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not having enough code to look at makes it hard to determine what exactly is causing the gap. Try to reset your li, img and a tags and see if it help. Add this to the top of your css file.

```
li, a, img{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 border:0;
}
```

If this doesn't work. You need to post more code to look at.

Answer (score 1):

if the `li`'s are floating already, add `display: block` to your images

Answer (score 1):

If there are gaps between li's that you're displaying using inline-block due to white space in the markup (new lines or spaces), you can remove it by using font-size: 0 on the containing element.